# Cloud Functions for Firebase onWrite timeout

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, timeout, google-cloud-functions

I return transaction promise which should wait for transaction to finish before stopping the function. The transaction executes fine, but the promise seems to never resolve.

I see in the Firebase console that this function always times out after 60s.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const db = admin.database();


export let countFollowers = functions.database.ref('followers/{followee}/{follower}').onWrite(event => {
    const followee = event.params.followee;
    let path = `posts/${followee}/cnt_foll`;
    const countRef = db.ref(path);
    let out = countRef.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (parseInt(current) || 0) + 1;
        } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (parseInt(current) || 0) - 1;
        }
    });

    return out;
});
```

EDIT:

I solve the problem with the following "hack", I create a promise myself, because whatever `.transaction` is returning is not working:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    countRef.transaction(current => {
        if (event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (parseInt(current) || 0) + 1;
        } else if (!event.data.exists() && event.data.previous.exists()) {
            return (parseInt(current) || 0) - 1; 
        }
    }, () => resolve(null));
});
```

Comment: It looks like an issue with `firebase` library itself.

Comment: This "hack" significantly lowered execution time of my cloud function.

Comment: For some reason, if you call `then` it works. Example `countRef.transaction(current => { .. }).then(() => { console.log("Transaction finished") })`

Answer (score 4):

There was a known issue with older versions of the firebase-admin SDK where Firebase Database references and snapshots couldn't be JSON serialized and thus couldn't be used in return values for Cloud Functions. This includes transaction return values since they also have snapshots.

Your hack works around the bug; you should also get the fix if you update your version of firebase-admin.

Comment: OK, will try to update to the latest `firebase-admin` at `4.1.4`, I am using version `4.1.3` BTW

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the latest version 4.1.4. I was following the example provided: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/child-count/functions/index.js

Comment: I can confirm that it's still an issue with `firebase-admin` `4.1.4` and `firebase-functions` `0.5.4`

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Clearly the fix wasnt enough. We can get it addressed in another release. You can work around it in the meantime with the code above.

Comment: The next backend update for Cloud Functions should fix this for all possible return types (instead of timing out the cloud function will log a warning and complete).